# tree.xpath returning empty list

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am attempting to write a program that can scrape a given website. So far I have this:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#{"numPax":2,"geo":"US","portsMatchAll":true,"numOptionsShown":20,"ppdIncludesTaxTips":true,"uiVersion":"split","sortTableByField":"dd","sortTableOrderDesc":false,"filter":null}')

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

date = tree.xpath('//*[@id="listingsTableSplit"]/tr[2]/td[1]/text()')

ship = tree.xpath('//*[@id="listingsTableSplit"]/tr[2]/td[2]/text()')

length = tree.xpath('//*[@id="listingsTableSplit"]/tr[2]/td[4]/text()')

meta = tree.xpath('//*[@id="listingsTableSplit"]/tr[2]/td[6]/text()')

price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="listingsTableSplit"]/tr[2]/td[7]/text()')

print('Date: ', date)
print('Ship: ', ship)
print('Length: ', length)
print('Meta: ', meta)
print('Price: ', price)
```

When this runs, the lists return empty.

I'm very new to python and coding in general and would appreciate any help you guys can provide!

Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to narrow down the issue?

Comment: If you are new to python and coding in general, then I'd suggest that you avoid web scraping initially. To begin with, you could learn the basics of programming and then try using web scraping libraries. Are you familiar with web pages, DOM, xpath, css, javascript ?

Comment: Thank you for your response but that is not helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the link you use is incorrect; this is the correct link (after you click the button 'yes' (the website will download data and return them to this link)):

```
https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#{%22numPax%22:2,%22geo%22:%22US%22,%22portsMatchAll%22:true,%22numOptionsShown%22:20,%22ppdIncludesTaxTips%22:true,%22uiVersion%22:%22split%22,%22sortTableByField%22:%22dd%22,%22sortTableOrderDesc%22:false,%22filter%22:null}
```

Second, when you use **requests** to get response object, content data inside the table are hidden are not returned:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

u = 'https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#{%22numPax%22:2,%22geo%22:%22US%22,%22portsMatchAll%22:true,%22numOptionsShown%22:20,%22ppdIncludesTaxTips%22:true,%22uiVersion%22:%22split%22,%22sortTableByField%22:%22dd%22,%22sortTableOrderDesc%22:false,%22filter%22:null}'
r = requests.get(u)
t = html.fromstring(r.content)

for i in t.xpath('//tr//text()'):
    print(i)
```

this will return :

```
Recent update: new computer-optimized interface and new filters
Want to track your favorite cruises?
Login or sign up to get started.
Login / Sign Up
Loading...
Email status
Unverified
My favorites & alerts
Log out
Want to track your favorite cruises?
Login or sign up to get started.
Login / Sign Up
Loading...
Email status
Unverified
My favorites & alerts
Log out
Date Colors:
(vs. selected)
Lowest Price
Lower Price
Same Price
Higher Price
```

Even if you use requests_html, the content still hidden

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(u)
```

You will need to access hidden html content using **selenium**:

```
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
import time

u = 'https://www.cruiseplum.com/search#{%22numPax%22:2,%22geo%22:%22US%22,%22portsMatchAll%22:true,%22numOptionsShown%22:20,%22ppdIncludesTaxTips%22:true,%22uiVersion%22:%22split%22,%22sortTableByField%22:%22dd%22,%22sortTableOrderDesc%22:false,%22filter%22:null}'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(u)

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id('restoreSettingsYesEncl').click()
time.sleep(10) #wait until the website downoad data, without this we can't move on

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")

t = html.fromstring(source_code)

for i in t.xpath('//td[@class="dc-table-column _1"]/text()'):
    print(i.strip())

driver.quit()
```

this return the first column (Vessels name) :

```
Costa Luminosa
Navigator Of The Seas
Navigator Of The Seas
Carnival Ecstasy
Carnival Ecstasy
Carnival Ecstasy
Carnival Victory
Carnival Victory
Carnival Victory
Costa Favolosa
Costa Favolosa
Costa Favolosa
Costa Smeralda
Carnival Inspiration
Carnival Inspiration
Carnival Inspiration
Costa Smeralda
Costa Smeralda
Disney Dream
Disney Dream
```

as you can see, content inside the table are now accesses using **get_attribute("innerHTML")** of selenium

Next step is to scrape rows (vessel, route, days, region..) and store them in csv file (or any other format),
Then do it for all the 4051 pages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the URL you're navigating to. Navigating to that URL in a browser results in a prompt asking if you want to restore your bookmarked search.

I didn't see a simple way around this. Clicking 'Yes' results in a javascript action, not an actual redirect with a different param.

I would suggest using something like selenium to accomplish this.